# Prob. 3 (c), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: If $\beta_j(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $\beta_j(x)=1$ if $x>0$ for $j=1, 2, 3$, and if . . .

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, proof-verification, definite-integrals

Here is Prob. 3, Chap. 6, in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin,3rd edition:

> Define three functions $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$, $\beta_3$ as follows: $\beta_j(x) = 0$ if $x < 0$, $\beta_j(x)=1$ if $x>0$ for $j=1, 2, 3$; and $\beta_1(0)=0$, $\beta_2(0) = 1$, $\beta_3(0) = \frac{1}{2}$. Let $f$ be a bounded function on $[ -1, 1]$.
>
> (a) Prove that $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\beta_1\right)$ if and only if $f(0+) = f(0)$ and that then 
>   $$ \int f \ \mathrm{d} \beta_1 = f(0). $$
>
> (b) State and prove a similar result for $\beta_2$.
>
> (c) Prove that $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\beta_3\right)$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at $0$.
>
> (d) If $f$ is continuous at $0$ prove that 
>   $$ \int f \ \mathrm{d}\beta_1 = \int f \ \mathrm{d}\beta_2 = \int f \ \mathrm{d}\beta_3 = f(0). $$

Here is the link to my post on Math SE on Prob. 3 (a), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition:

[Prob. 3 (a), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: If $\beta_j(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $\beta_j(x)=1$ for $x>0$ and $f$ is bounded on $[-1, 1]$, . . .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373383/prob-3-a-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-if-beta-jx-0-for-x0-and-beta-jx)

And, here is the link to my post here on Math SE on Prob. 3 (b), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin:

[Prob. 3 (b), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: If $\beta_j(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $\beta_j(x)=1$ if $x>0$, then . . .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373475/prob-3-b-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-if-beta-jx-0-if-x0-and-beta-jx)

My Attempt of Part (c):

> Let us choose a real number $\varepsilon > 0$.
>
> Suppose that $f$ is continuous at $0$. Then we can find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that 
>   $$ \lvert f(x) - f(0) \rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{8} \tag{0} $$
>   for all real numbers $x \in [-1, 1]$ for which $\lvert x-0 \rvert < \delta$. Let us choose our  $\delta \in (0, 1)$.
>
> Let $n$ be a natural number such that $n > 3$. Let $P = \{ \ x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n \ \}$ be a partition of $[-1, 1]$ such that $0$ is one of the points, say $x_j$ (for some $j \in \{ 1, \ldots, n-1 \ \}$,  of $P$, and such that $\Delta x_i < \frac{\delta}{2}$ for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$.
>
> Then as $x_{j-1} < x_j = 0 < x_{j+1}$, so 
>   $$
> \begin{align} 
> L \left( P, f, \beta_3 \right) &= \sum_{i=1}^n m_i \left[ \beta_3 \left( x_i \right) - \beta_3 \left( x_{i-1} \right) \right] \\
> &= m_j \left[ \beta_3\left(x_j\right) - \beta_3\left(x_{j-1} \right) \right] + m_{j+1} \left[ \beta_3\left(x_{j+1} \right) - \beta_3\left(x_{j} \right) \right] \\
> &=  m_j \left( \frac{1}{2} - 0 \right) + m_{j+1} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2} \right) \\
> &= \frac{m_j + m_{j+1} }{2}, \tag{A} 
> \end{align}
> $$ 
>   and similarly 
>   $$
> \begin{align} 
> U \left( P, f, \beta_3 \right) &= \sum_{i=1}^n M_i \left[ \beta_3 \left( x_i \right) - \beta_3 \left( x_{i-1} \right) \right] \\
> &= M_j \left[ \beta_3\left(x_j\right) - \beta_3\left(x_{j-1} \right) \right] + M_{j+1} \left[ \beta_3\left(x_{j+1} \right) - \beta_3\left(x_{j} \right) \right] \\
> &=  M_j \left( \frac{1}{2} - 0 \right) + M_{j+1} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2} \right) \\
> &= \frac{M_j + M_{j+1} }{2}. \tag{B}
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Now as $\Delta x_i < \frac{\delta}{2}$ for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$ and as $x_j = 0$, so 
>   $$ -\frac{\delta}{2} < x_{j-1} < 0 < x_{j+1} < \frac{\delta}{2},$$ 
>   and therefore 
>   $$ \left[ x_{j-1}, x_{j+1} \right] \subset (-\delta, \delta), $$ 
>   and then from (0) we can conclude that 
>   $$ \lvert f(x) - f(0) \rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{8}  $$
>   for all $x \in \left[ x_{j-1}, x_{j+1} \right]$. That is, 
>   $$ f(0) - \frac{\varepsilon}{8} < f(x) < f(0) + \frac{\varepsilon}{8} $$ 
>   for all  $x \in \left[ x_{j-1}, x_{j+1} \right]$. So we have the inequalities 
>   $$ f(0) - \frac{\varepsilon}{8} \leq m_j \leq M_j \leq f(0) + \frac{\varepsilon}{8}, $$ 
>   and 
>   $$ f(0) - \frac{\varepsilon}{8} \leq m_{j+1} \leq M_{j+1} \leq f(0) + \frac{\varepsilon}{8}. $$ 
>   By adding the last two chains of inequalities and then dividing the resulting chain out by $2$ we obtain 
>   $$ f(0) - \frac{ \varepsilon }{ 8 } \leq \frac{ m_j + m_{ j + 1 } }{2} \leq \frac{ M_j + M_{j+1 } }{ 2 } \leq f(0) + \frac{\varepsilon }{8}, $$
>   which together with (A) and (B) above implies that 
>   $$ f(0) - \frac{\varepsilon}{8} \leq L \left( P, f, \beta_3 \right) \leq U \left( P, f, \beta_3 \right) \leq f(0) + \frac{\varepsilon}{8}, \tag{1} $$
>   and this in turn implies that 
>   $$ U \left( P, f, \beta_3 \right) - L \left( P, f, \beta_3 \right) \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{4} < \varepsilon, $$
>   and this by virtue of Theorem 6.6 in Baby Rudin implies that $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\beta_3\right)$ on $[-1, 1]$.

Is this part of the proof correct?

> Conversely, suppose that $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\beta_3\right)$ on $[-1, 1]$. Then by Theorem 6.6 in Baby Rudin, there exists a partition $Q$ of $[-1, 1]$ such that 
>   $$ U \left( Q, f, \beta_3 \right) -  L \left( Q, f, \beta_3 \right) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. \tag{2} $$
>
> Now let $P = \left\{ \ x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n \ \right\}$ be a partition of $[-1, 1]$ such that $P \supset Q$ and such that $P$ contains $0$ as one of its points; let us suppose that $x_j = 0$ for some $j \in \{ \ 1, \ldots, n - 1 \ \}$.
>
> As $P$ is a refinement of $Q$, so by Theorem 4.4 in Baby Rudin we have 
>   $$ L \left( Q, f, \beta_3 \right) \leq L \left( P, f, \beta_3 \right) \leq U \left( P, f, \beta_3 \right) \leq U \left( Q, f, \beta_3 \right), $$ 
>   and so 
>   $$ U \left( P, f, \beta_3 \right) - L \left( P, f, \beta_3 \right) \leq  U \left( Q, f, \beta_3 \right) - L \left( Q, f, \beta_3 \right), $$
>   which together with (2) implies that 
>   $$ U \left( P, f, \beta_3 \right) - L \left( P, f, \beta_3 \right) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. \tag{3} $$
>
> Now using (A) and (B) in (3) we obtain 
>   $$ \frac{ M_j + M_{j+1} }{2} - \frac{ m_j + m_{j+1} }{2} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}, $$
>   which is the same as 
>   $$ \frac{M_j - m_j}{2} + \frac{M_{j+1} - m_{j+1} }{2} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}. \tag{4} $$ 
>   But as $M_j - m_j \geq 0$ and $M_{j+1} - m_{j+1} \geq 0$, so (4) implies that 
>   $$ \frac{M_j - m_j}{2} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad  \frac{M_{j+1} - m_{j+1} }{2} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}; $$ 
>   therefore 
>   $$ M_j - m_j < \varepsilon \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad M_{j+1} - m_{j+1} < \varepsilon. \tag{5} $$
>
> Now let $\delta$ be any real number such that 
>   $$ 0 < \delta < \min \left\{ \ \Delta x_j, \ \Delta x_{j+1} \ \right\} =  \min \left\{ \ x_j - x_{j-1}, \ x_{j+1} - x_j \ \right\} = \min \left\{ \ - x_{j-1} , \ x_{j+1} \ \right\}.  $$ 
>   Then  we know that our choice of $\delta$ implies  that 
>   $$ x_{j-1} < -\delta < 0 < \delta < x_{j+1}. \tag{6} $$
>
> Now if $x$ is any real number which satisfies $$ \lvert x-0 \rvert < \delta,$$  then that $x$ also satisfies $$ - \delta < x < \delta, $$ 
>   and hence (6) implies that that real number $x$ also satisfies 
>   $$ x_{j-1} < x < x_{j+1}, $$ 
>   and therefore such an $x$ belongs to 
>   $ \left[ x_{j-1}, x_{j+1} \right]$. But 
>   $$ \left[ x_{j-1}, x_{j+1} \right] = \left[ x_{j-1}, x_j \right] \cup \left[ x_j, x_{j+1} \right]. $$ 
>   Thus any real number $x$ which satisfies $\lvert x-0 \rvert < \delta$ must belong to at least one of the intervals $\left[ x_{j-1}, x_j \right]$ and $\left[x_j, x_{j+1} \right]$, and so we must have 
>   $$ m_j \leq f(x) \leq M_j  \qquad \mbox{ or } \qquad m_{j+1} \leq f(x) \leq M_{j+1} \tag{7} $$ 
>   for any real number $x$ such that $\lvert x-0 \rvert < \delta$.
>
> Since both the inequalities in (7) hold for $x_j = 0$, therefore we can conclude from (7) that 
>   $$ \lvert f(x) - f(0) \rvert \leq \max  \left\{ \ M_j - m_j, \ M_{j+1} - m_{j+1} \ \right\} \tag{8} $$ 
>   for any real number $x$ such that $\lvert x-0 \rvert < \delta$.
>
> From (5) and (8) we can conclude that 
>   $$ \lvert f(x) - f(0) \rvert < \varepsilon $$ 
>   for any real number $x$ such that $\lvert x-0 \rvert < \delta$. Thus it follows that $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Is this  proof of the converse part correct?

> Thus we have shown that $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\beta_3\right)$ on $[-1, 1]$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at $0$. In that case we also have 
>   $$ L \left( Q, f, \beta_3 \right) \leq \int_{-1}^1 f \ \mathrm{d} \beta_3 \leq U \left( Q, f, \beta_3 \right) $$
>   for any partition $Q$ of $[-1, 1]$; so (1) implies that 
>   $$ f(0) - \frac{\varepsilon}{8} \leq \int_{-1}^1 f \ \mathrm{d} \beta_3 \leq f(0) + \frac{\varepsilon}{8}, $$
>   which in turn implies that 
>   $$ \left\lvert \int_{-1}^1 f \ \mathrm{d} \beta_3 \ - \ f(0) \right\rvert < \varepsilon $$
>   for any real number $\varepsilon > 0$. Hence 
>   $$ \int_{-1}^1 f \ \mathrm{d} \beta_3 = f(0). $$

Is this the correct conclusion about $\int_{-1}^1 f \ \mathrm{d} \beta_3 $, and if so, then is it derived using the correct procedure?

Comment: The same down-vote!! What's so offensive about my post, I wonder?