# Prob. 3 (d), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: If $\beta_j(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $\beta_j(x)=1$ for $x>0$ and if $f$ is . . .

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

Here is Prob. 3, Chap. 6, in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin,3rd edition:

> Define three functions $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$, $\beta_3$ as follows: $\beta_j(x) = 0$ if $x < 0$, $\beta_j(x)=1$ if $x>0$ for $j=1, 2, 3$; and $\beta_1(0)=0$, $\beta_2(0) = 1$, $\beta_3(0) = \frac{1}{2}$. Let $f$ be a bounded function on $[ -1, 1]$.
>
> (a) Prove that $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\beta_1\right)$ if and only if $f(0+) = f(0)$ and that then 
>   $$ \int f \ \mathrm{d} \beta_1 = f(0). $$
>
> (b) State and prove a similar result for $\beta_2$.
>
> (c) Prove that $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\beta_3\right)$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at $0$.
>
> (d) If $f$ is continuous at $0$ prove that 
>   $$ \int f \ \mathrm{d}\beta_1 = \int f \ \mathrm{d}\beta_2 = \int f \ \mathrm{d}\beta_3 = f(0). $$

Here are the links to my earlier posts here on Math SE on Probs. 3 (a), (b), and (c), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition:

[Prob. 3 (a), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: If $\beta_j(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $\beta_j(x)=1$ for $x>0$ and $f$ is bounded on $[-1, 1]$, . . .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373383/prob-3-a-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-if-beta-jx-0-for-x0-and-beta-jx)

[Prob. 3 (b), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: If $\beta_j(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $\beta_j(x)=1$ if $x>0$, then . . .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373475/prob-3-b-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-if-beta-jx-0-if-x0-and-beta-jx)

[Prob. 3 (c), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: If $\beta_j(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $\beta_j(x)=1$ if $x>0$ for $j=1, 2, 3$, and if . . .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373652/prob-3-c-chap-6-in-baby-rudin-if-beta-jx-0-if-x0-and-beta-jx)

Here I'll attempt a solution to Prob. 3 (d).

My Attempt of Part (d):

> If $f$ is continuous at $0$, then $f \in \mathscr{R} \left( \beta_3 \right)$ on $[-1, 1]$ (by Prob. 3 (c), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition), and (as in my post on Pob. 3 (c), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition) we also have 
>   $$ \int_{-1}^1 f \ \mathrm{d} \beta_3 = f(0). \tag{1} $$
>
> Moreover, if $f$ is continuous at $0$, then we also have  $$ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0), $$ which implies that 
>   $$ f(0+) = f(0) =  f(0-).  $$ 
>   So by Probs. 3 (a) and (b), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin we can conclude that 
>   $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\beta_1\right)$ and $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\beta_2\right)$ on $[-1, 1]$, and that 
>   $$ \int_{-1}^1 f \ \mathrm{d} \beta_1 = f(0) =  \int_{-1}^1 f \ \mathrm{d} \beta_2. \tag{2} $$
>
> From (1) and (2) we have our desired result.

Are there any problems with my proof?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, but this post (in its entirety) is not at all a duplicate of any of my earlier posts. The confusion is because I've included in all four of my posts the entire Prob. 3, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition. However, I've attempted only a singe part of that problem in any given post. So no two of the posts are duplicates of each other.

Comment: @amWhy please read through the two posts carefully and you'll see that these aren't duplicates of each other. Or, please read my comment above.

Comment: As I said in a very recent comment, this sight isn't a whiteboard so progress with three/four separate versions of the same thing.  You are always free to edit and update your original question.

Comment: @amWhy but that will make that particular post too lengthy, won't it? Imagine how lengthy my post on Prob. 3(a), Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin would get if I edited / updated it to include my attempts of the Parts (b), (c), and (d) also! Please have a look at all the four posts one by one, and you'll then have an idea!

Comment: this site isn't meant to be an editorial site.  You can not post a question (submit a proof), then fine tune it and resubmit, and then fine tune and "re-resubmit" it, .... It's quite the nerve to post and repost very lengthy proofs or questions, with the presumption that users are obliged to read each and every update, when you should have taken the time to consider and reconsider and then edit the original post.

Comment: I have read them all;  If you have a question about part of a proof, ask it.  Proof verification, as a tag, does not apply to excessively long proofs.  You are free to ask a **very specific** question.

Comment: @amWhy yes, I agree to what you've just suggested. But it is only to make my post easier to follow that I've edited it. I'm sorry if this is unagreeable with the learned Math SE community.

Comment: Bottom line: You are as much part of the community as anyone less.  I'm simply suggesting that you consider what your expectations of others are when you ask such questions.  It is absolutely clear that you have dedicated a significant amount of time to thinking about Rudin's Chapter 6, and some of its exercises.  I admire you for that.  I will undelete the post, but there may be others seeking to close it.  Cheers!